# How can I calculate Fibonacci retracements levels for stocks correctly -- not like 99% of the world does it?

Tags: logarithms, fibonacci-numbers

If a stock travels from 40 to 100, a common belief is that a 50% retracement means that of the 60 move, half is given back, or 30. For a 38.2% retracement, prevalent thinking is that it's .382(60), or 22.92 that the stock should give back, or 100 - $22.92 = 77.08.

But, this assumes arithmetic scaling of the y-axis (the price axis), and investing isn't arithmetic.

For example, 40 to 100 is a big move of 150%. The 50% retracement back to 70 suggests that a move from 40 to 70 equates to a move from 70 to 100. Is that true? If you, the investor, could choose whether you get to own the stock from 40 to 70 or 70 to 100, which scenario would you choose? The correct answer is 40 to 70, which is a 75% increase. What is the increase from 70 to 100? It is 42.9%. Seventy is NOT the middle of 40 and 100. To find the middle, take the geometric mean, or square root of the product of 40 and 100, to get 63.25. That's the level where we can say that a move from 40 to 63.25 is the same as 63.25 to 100. Yet, 63.25 is only 23.25 away from 40, and 36.75 away from 100.

This is where my logarithmic math memory fails me. I don't know how to find the other retracement levels, like the common 38.2% and 61.8% and less common but still important 23.6% and 73.4% ones.

I can estimate the 38.2% retracement of 40 to 100 as 70.58 (plus/minus a penny or two), and the 61.8% retracement at 56.75.

So, what do I do with 40, 100, and .382 to get 70.58, for example?

Thank you!  This has plagued me for 21 years, ever since TradeStation decided it would remove the checkbox from its retracement tool that asked the user "Arithmetic or logarithmic?". Their reasoning was that no one would ever need logarithmic calculations --- and this is true if we're worried about the 38.2% retracement of a stock that moved from 99 to 100. But, when stocks like GME move from 3 to 430, it's critical to calculate logarithmically.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just log the ratio of new/old. Do whatever percentage arithmetic you want on the log. Then exponentiate it to remove the log and multiply it into the old.

Comment: Hi Don!  You give me too much credit! Could you please give me an example?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:
Let the original price, old, be 3000
Let the top price, new, be 5000
We find the logarithmic fibonacci levels like this:

Let m be an intermediary variable
m = ln(new/old)

If we want to find the 0.382 level we need to calculate old * e^(0.382*m)

Hope that helps,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, had to develop my custom solution. Posting it here for anyone it helps - >

```
levels = [ 0, 0.236, 0.382, 0.5, 0.618, 0.786, 1]

def fibonacci_levels_log_based(high_low):
    high, low = high_low
    global levels
    log_pricelow, log_pricehigh = np.log10(low), np.log10(high)
    log_price_ratio = log_pricehigh - log_pricelow

    # Calculate Fibonacci extension levels in logarithmic scale
    log_fib_levels = [log_pricelow + level * log_price_ratio for level in levels]

    # Convert Logarithmic Levels Back to Original Scale
    fib_levels = [10**level for level in log_fib_levels]
    return fib_levels

values = fibonacci_levels_log_based([100,40])
print(values)
```